# How to Have Smaller Intervals in TimeSeries

Tags: plotting, manipulate, list-manipulation, animation, time-series

I have a wolfram demonstration project with the following code:

```
Manipulate[
 
 dist = 5;
 
 posA = -dist;
 posB = dist;
 vA2 = -((-mA vA1 + ee mB vA1 - mB vB1 - ee mB vB1)/(mA + mB));
 vB2 = -((-mA vA1 - ee mA vA1 + ee mA vB1 - mB vB1)/(mA + mB));
 
 (* vA1*t-dist+mA/10=vB1*t+dist+mB/10, (vA1-vB1)*t=2*dist+mB/10 *)
 tImpact = (20 dist - mA - mB)/(10 (vA1 - vB1));
 
 posImpactA = posA + vA1 tImpact;
 posImpactB = posB + vB1 tImpact;
 c1 = (vA2 - vA1)/2 Tanh[ (10 x)/dt - (10 tImpact)/dt] + (vA2 + vA1)/2;
 c2 = (vB2 - vB1)/2 Tanh[(10 x)/dt - (10 tImpact)/dt] + (vB1 + vB2)/2;
 
 posA2 = If[tt <= tImpact, vA1 tt + posA, 
   posImpactA + vA2*(tt - tImpact)];
 posB2 = If[tt <= tImpact, vB1 tt + posB, 
   posImpactB + vB2*(tt - tImpact)];
 
 vecB = If[
   tt <= tImpact,
   {Red, Thick, Arrow[{{posB2, 0}, {posB2 + vB1, 0}}]},
   {Darker[Green], Thick, Arrow[{{posB2, 0}, {posB2 + vB2, 0}}]}
   ];
 vecA = If[
   tt <= tImpact,
   {Red, Thick, Arrow[{{posA2, 0}, {posA2 + vA1, 0}}]},
   {Darker[Green], Thick, Arrow[{{posA2, 0}, {posA2 + vA2, 0}}]}
   ];
 If[sh,
  Show[
   Plot[Tooltip[{vA1, vB1}], {tt, 0, tImpact - dt/2}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {-10, 10}}, 
    PlotStyle -> {{AbsoluteThickness[3]}, {AbsoluteThickness[3]}}, 
    PlotLabel -> "velocity versus time", 
    AxesLabel -> {t , Subscript[v, x]}],
   Plot[Tooltip[{vA2, vB2}], {tt, tImpact + dt/2, 5}, 
    PlotStyle -> {{AbsoluteThickness[3]}, {AbsoluteThickness[3]}}],
   Plot[{c1, c2}, {x, tImpact - dt/2, tImpact + dt/2}, 
    PlotStyle -> {{AbsoluteThickness[3]}, {AbsoluteThickness[3]}}],
   ImageSize -> {550, 275}], 
  timeSeries = 
   Table[{vA1, vB1, vA2, vB2, tt}, {tt, 0.1, tImpact + dt/2, 5}], 
  Graphics[{
    (* road *) {Lighter[Gray], Arrow[{{-10, 0}, {10, 0}}]},
    (* disk for A *) {RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], 
     EdgeForm[Black], Disk[{posA2, 0}, mA/10]},
    (* disk for B *) {RGBColor[0.880722, 0.611041, 0.142051], 
     EdgeForm[Black], Disk[{posB2, 0}, mB/10]}, vecA, vecB}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-6.6, 6.6}}, ImageSize -> {550, 275}]
  ],
 Grid[{
   {
    Spacer[40],
    Control[{{mA, 1, "mass of A"}, 1, 10, 0.1, 
      Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Small}], 
    Control[{{vA1, 5, "initial velocity of A"}, 1, 5, 0.1, 
      Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Small}]
    },
   {
    Spacer[40],
    Control[{{mB, 10, "mass of B"}, 1, 10, 0.1, 
      Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Small}], 
    Control[{{vB1, 0, "initial velocity of B"}, -5, 0, 
      Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Small}]
    },
   {
    Spacer[40],
    Control[{{tt, 0, "time"}, 0, 5, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
      ImageSize -> Small}], 
    Control[{{ee, 1, "coefficient of elasticity"}, 0, 1, 0.1, 
      Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Small}]
    },
   {
    Spacer[40],
    Control[{{sh, False, "velocity plot"}, {True, False}, 
      ImageSize -> Small}], 
    Control[{{dt, 0.1, "collision time"}, 0.01, 1.5, 
      Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Small}]
    }
   },
  Alignment -> Left],
 TrackedSymbols -> True,
 AutorunSequencing -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7}]
Export["file.txt", timeSeries, "Table"]
```

I modified it so that I can get a Table of the initial and final velocities of both masses over time using the timeSeries and Table function. The problem is when I open the file I get:

```
5   0   -45/11  10/11   1.83
5   0   -45/11  10/11   2.83
5   0   -45/11  10/11   3.83
5   0   -45/11  10/11   4.83
```

How can I modify it so that I can get the velocities at smaller time intervals, for example 0.1 seconds instead of 1 second as shown in the table that I generated.

******EDIT******

I am as can be seen from the graph generated from the demonstration trying to find the velocities when it changes during the collision:

[image]

Thank you.

*****EDIT****
Based on the answer below I get a table that looks like:

```
7/4 {4.977521607666957, 0.0022478392333043495}
351/200 {4.93915590068832, 0.006084409931168044}
44/25   {4.836489000344622, 0.016351099965537796}
353/200 {4.5688556983857564, 0.043114430161424355}
177/100 {3.916337072526204, 0.10836629274737963}
71/40   {2.555077987545499, 0.24449220124545012}
89/50   {0.45454545454545453, 0.45454545454545453}
357/200 {-1.6459870784545898, 0.6645987078454589}
179/100 {-3.007246163435295, 0.8007246163435294}
359/200 {-3.6597647892948477, 0.8659764789294847}
9/5 {-3.9273980912537136, 0.8927398091253713}
361/200 {-4.030064991597412, 0.9030064991597411}
181/100 {-4.068430698576049, 0.9068430698576047}
363/200 {-4.082626807323631, 0.908262680732363}
91/50   {-4.087860453359396, 0.9087860453359395}
73/40   {-4.089787322036489, 0.9089787322036489}
```

Are the terms in the brackets the final velocities of the mass A and mass B and outside the brackets is the time? How can I insert the initial velocities as well?
Also, how can I get rid of the brackets so that I can use this data automatically.

Comment: Please correct the errors in your code.

Comment: My code isn't working properly. My code is my (failed) attempt to modify the original code (posted first) to get the velocities. But I need help with it. I added an extra explanation of what I am looking for under ***EDIT**** in my question. I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inserted some code, that will calculate 100 time steps between t=0..5. The output is available outside the `Manipulate` in variable `velocities`. It corresponds to the current setting. If you want more resolution, feel free to change the time step in the `Table` command.

The first number in a row is the time, The next two, the initial and the last to the final velocities.

Here is the inserted code

```
....

vecA = If[
   tt <= tImpact, {Red, Thick, 
    Arrow[{{posA2, 0}, {posA2 + vA1, 0}}]}, {Darker[Green], Thick, 
    Arrow[{{posA2, 0}, {posA2 + vA2, 0}}]}];

vel[t_] = Piecewise[{
    {{vA1, vB1}, 0 <= t < tImpact - dt/2},
    {{c1, c2} /. x -> t, tImpact - dt/2 <= t < tImpact + dt/2},
    {{vA2, vB2}, tImpact - dt/2 <= t <= 5},
    {0, True}
    }];
velocities = 
  Table[{t, vA1, vB1, Sequence @@ vel[t]}//N, {t, 0, 5, 5/100}];    


If[sh, Show[Plot[Tooltip[{vA1, vB1}], {tt, 0, tImpact - dt/2},

....
```

Comment: Thank you, I had a couple more questions under my last edit in my question to clarify your answer.

Comment: I added the changes in my answer.

Comment: Thank you! One last thing: Can we have the outputs in decimals instead of fractions.

Comment: I see it now. I wasn't sure how to insert N. But I got it now. Thanks for the updates and help!!